# Is it possible to @InjectMocks into a temporary object instance in the method of a class?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Consider code snippet below:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTest {
    @InjectMocks ClassA cA;
    @Mock Helper hlpr;

    @Test
    void doStuff() {
        ClassB cB = new ClassB(cA);
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ClassA {
    public ClassA() {
        this.myattribute = (new Helper()).action;
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I just need the Helper class for its function, so it's not added in as a private variable to ClassA. Any workaround without changing ClassA?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at mocking myattribute rather than the Helper class. Does myattribute have a setter you can use for the test? I think their are ways around a setter using something like powemock but these issues normally point to a problem with your implementation

Comment: Unfortunately there is no setters for it. Why would using powermock show an issue with the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

`Mock` is used to mock the dependencies of the class you want to test (annoted with   `@InjectMocks`) in order to do unit testing. So if you want to write an unit test on your class A, it seems that you should `@Mock` `myattribute`

Comment: Wouldn't the line of code still run and execute this.myattribute = (new Helper()).action ? Wouldn't that override my mock?

Comment: it will run but after that myattribute will be replaced by a mock object so the override is the other way around. And of course you provide the behaviour of the mock using Mockito.when()

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, that is one of the problems because I can't let that line of code to run in my test environment or else things will crash. Any way to bypass this?

Comment: If you don't want to call ClassA's constructor the only way is to annotate cA like that : @Mock ClassA cA. But it's means that you are not unit testing ClassA anymore... From what i see that line of code always run in every environment so you probably have a design issue if it cannot run on test environment